# Ajax : How to store all sequantialUpload into one array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm using Ajax for a fileupload app that list the uploaded files without refreshing the page, the user can then download all the files uploaded as `.zip`.

The problem is that I'd like to send (POST method) an array with all the files path to my backend so they can be compressed as `.zip` and I have some issues storing them all the paths into one single array like this : `array = ['path1', 'path2', 'path3']`

Since the files are uploaded one by one here is what happens to my array on `console.log()` :

```
array = ['path1']
array = ['path2']
array = ['path3']
...
```

The backend expect all the files to be sent directly in one array in order to group them in a `.zip` file. How can I do it ?

**Here's the ajax upload code :**

```
$("#fileupload").fileupload({

dataType: 'json',
sequentialUploads: true,  /* SEND THE FILES ONE BY ONE */

done: function (e, data) {
  if (data.result.is_valid) {

    mylist = [];
    mylist.push(data.result.url);
    console.log(mylist); /* HERE IS THE CONSOLE.LOG() */

    $(document).on('submit', '#formDownload', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
            if($(this).is('#formDownload')) {
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'/tools/getfiles/',
                    data:{
                        path:mylist, /* array that'll be received by the backend*/
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('#formDownload input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                    },
                });
            }
    });
  }
}

});
```

Is there any way to resolve this ?

Comment: I think we need a little more information here. is `$.fileupload` a plugin you are using? Perhaps [this one](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)? Are you uploading filenames (strings) or actual files?

Comment: @SpencerAvinger Yes it is a plugin, I'm uploading actual files, but for the list I just need the files paths

Comment: You'll need a special solution on your backend. What are you using? PHP?

Comment: @SpencerAvinger I'm on Django (python), I also receive the datas like this on the backend so I thought it had to do with ajax.

Comment: From the documentation [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki#python)... Django integration [tutorial](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com/2011/07/django-creating-multi-upload-form.html) and [demo code](https://github.com/garmoncheg/django_multiuploader_demo).

Comment: @SpencerAvinger Sorry, this doesn't solve my issue, I'm not trying to change my uploader for a different one, I'm trying to use this one for specific reasons. I do have a way to make my code work but it requires a hidden input which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I think you should declare `mylist = [];` outside as a global variable then do the push inside done method.Probably currently it's overriding the previous value and you are getting the last inserted value.